# JavaFXPorts: Selected item in ListView is not selected

Tags: javafx, javafxports, gluon-mobile

Here is sample code:

```
package com.javafxportslistviewdemo;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.Platform;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.Services;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.LifecycleEvent;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.LifecycleService;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXPortsListViewDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Screen primaryScreen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D visualBounds = primaryScreen.getVisualBounds();
        double width = visualBounds.getWidth();
        double height = visualBounds.getHeight();

        Label label = new Label("Here is selected item...");

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "one", "two", "three", "four");
        listView.setItems(items);
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String old_val, String new_val) -> {
            label.setText(new_val);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(label, listView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);

        Services.get(LifecycleService.class).ifPresent(ls -> {
            ls.addListener(LifecycleEvent.PAUSE, () -> onPause());
            ls.addListener(LifecycleEvent.RESUME, () -> onResume());
        });

        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
            if (KeyCode.ESCAPE.equals(e.getCode())) {
                if (Platform.isAndroid()) {
                    // bring up the menu or other Android stuff
                    Services.get(LifecycleService.class).ifPresent(LifecycleService::shutdown);
                } else {
                    // bring up the menu or other Desktop stuff
                    Services.get(LifecycleService.class).ifPresent(LifecycleService::shutdown);
                }
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void onPause() {
    }

    private void onResume() {
    }
}
```

Environment for development: JavaFXPorts 8.60.8, javafxmobile-plugin 1.1.0, Gluon Plugin 2.4.0, NetBeans 8.1, Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit

Environment for testing: Android device Samsung Galaxy A5 2016, Android 6.0.1

Steps to reproduce: 1. Build sample code with: JavaFXPorts 8.60.8, javafxmobile-plugin 1.1.0, Gluon Plugin 2.4.0; 2. Install and Run sample on Android device (Android 6.0.1); 3. Touch on ListView and Select any item from ListView - item is not selected -> BUG

Added bug for issue tracker of JavaFXPorts: [JavaFXPorts issue](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/85/selected-item-in-listview-is-not-selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue.

It is already known that in some Samsung devices the touch event handling doesn't work as in the rest of Android devices.

While this is fixed in JavaFXPorts, you can use the following workaround: provide a listener to the `ListCell` that wires internally the selection.

Based on your sample:

```
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    listView.setCellFactory(p -> new ListCell<String>() {

        private String item;
        {
            setOnMouseClicked(e -> listView.getSelectionModel().select(item));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty); 
            this.item = item;
            setText(item);
        }

    });
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
      .addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> label.setText(new_val));
```

Comment: Your workaround is acceptable. Thanks. ... and would you like something to say [ComboBox behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373812/javafxports-is-this-correct-behavior-for-javafx-scene-control-combobox-on-andro)

Comment: What about adding this to the cell instead of the mouse listener: `{ listView.getSelectionModel().select(item); }`

Comment: Styling is not working still and selecting item is not working again.

Comment: Can you try this: `{ setOnMouseClicked(e -> listView.getSelectionModel().select(item)); }`? (I can't reproduce it)

Comment: For me is full working workaround is: `{
                setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                    label.setText(item);
                    listView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                });
            }` ... and styling and selecting is working. Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the `label.setText()` part if you keep the original listener in `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()`. I've edited my answer with it.