# android tablet and compatibility with javafxports gluon - additional useful info

Tags: android, javafx, tablet, gluon, javafxports

I have created an video game for smartphones (with javafx, gluon, ...) . I have tested it on several mobiles (Archos Diamond S with Lollipop, Sony XPeria T2 Ultra with Android 5.1, Wiko Lenny 3 with Android 6.0 Marshmallow, ...). All works fine.

But, when I have installed this game (.apk ) on a Android tablet Samsung A 9.7 with Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow):

The funny reason is that I had restricted the game use to the mobiles. So, to extend the game use to tablets, add that tablet condition (with Services) as follows:

```
Services.get(DisplayService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
        boolean bAndroidSmartphone = service.isPhone();
        **boolean bAndroidTablet = service.isTablet();**
        traceSimple("hg_1");
        if (bAndroidSmartphone || bAndroidTablet) {
```

That condition implicitely avoids using the game on desktop

Comment: Samsung... yes, that rings the bell. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40482995/3956070). Some events need `setMouseClicked` or `setMousePressed` instead of `setOnAction`. About the accelerometer I can't say. If you could try a small test in that device, you could check the Down services compass or magnetometer? If it wasn't detected you should see in the output `"No accelerometer available"`.

Comment: José: in this case, Samsung is a tablet, not a desktop (Personal computer). The trouble is about tablets

Comment: I didn't say anything about desktop. The device with more reports so far is the Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: José: I made a mistake. For understanding that, see the additional info above. My game works fine on mobile AND tablet with only an additional test :) And Samsung Galaxy Tab A works fine