# textfield & combobox problem in javafx android

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am having problem in simple javafx android app.
The problem is that i build very simple app with some text-fields and combobox in netbeans ide using gradle javafxmobile-plugin.
I run the app in android the textfield and combobox causes problem in android mobile .
The problem is that when i typed from keyboard in android nothing changes in text-field until i press space button, or choose suggestion in keyboard upper area.
Also when i type some text in text-field and switch another then the text transfor on other textfield which i typed using keyboard rather then orignal text-field.
The other problem i notis is that when i select value in combobox nothing changes. some time after tyring again and again changes. Also combobox allow multiple selects...

### The working status of app on android devices....

### working:

Company
Sumsung

Model number
QMobile Z10

Android version
5.1

---

### not working:

Company
Sumsung

Model number
GT-190601

Android version
4.4.4

---

Company
Sumsung

Model number
SM-G900F

Android version
6.0.1

This is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.androidcontrols.Main'

dependencies {

}

jfxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.11'

    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a similar question reported for the `ComboBox` issue, with a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484483/3956070). If you are using a Gluon TextField with auto complete, a `ListView` is used in the `Popup`, and for that there is another issue with solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40482995/3956070).

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it sounds like the text element used by JavaFxPorts doesn't correctly handle composing text (which probably isn't a concept in JavaFx as it only makes sense on a highly autocomplete driven model like mobile).  Words appear when you hit space because then the composing region is committed.  If that's the case, the fix would be to fix javafx, or use a keyboard app that doesn't use the composing text paradigm.  In particular the fix would be to display the text in the composing region, which it doesn't seem to be doing.

You may have some luck by setting the type of the input field to TYPE_NULL and telling the keyboard app to assume the editor attached to it is stupid/broken.  But then you'll be losing features of the keyboard app in doing so.

Comment: Thanks for ver soon response.

Comment: Actualy my mobile have auto-complete feature so when i select some of them the text entered in textfield. But how i get ride of it if i whant auto comple feature in my mobile with this app....