# Gluon TextField Updating Issue Android 10

Tags: gluon-mobile

I have an issue with updating content of a TextField during writing on a nativ Android keyboard.
The problem is that the input text is not displayed until the space or enter button is pressed. I  observed this behaviour on Samsung S10e Android 10. I tried the same app on different device (Lenovo Android 7) and it behaves as expected - The text is updated after single button press.

I've found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376368/textfield-combobox-problem-in-javafx-android) but there is no solution or workaround for my case.

Is there any way to force the TextField to update?

Comment: What is your jfxmobile plugin version?

Comment: org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16

Comment: Update to 1.3.18 and try again. There are some fixes that might help.

Comment: It's a shame but the update didn't help.

Comment: If I get it right, you can type any character, but you don't see anything until you press space or enter? Can you add a listener to the `textField.textProperty()` to print to the console any change. Then start typing and see if that shows up (use `adb logcat` to find out)?

Comment: Exactly, the text is shown after pressing space or enter. I've added a listener to the TextField and I saw  a printout  after pressing space or enter only. While I'm writing there are no printout int log.

Comment: Can you give it a try to the new Client plugin? See https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples. Add a `TextField` control to HelloFX and deploy to your Android device (you need a Linux machine though).